# Subgroup of the center that is not Characteristic subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Good morning everyone,

I'm looking for a subgroup of $Z(G)$ the center of the group $G$ that is not characteristic subgroup of $G$.

Did someone have that in his pocket ?

I wish you a very good day !

Comment: Any such subgroup will be normal, but not necessarily characteristic, see the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1254906/a-normal-subgroup-that-is-not-a-characteristic).

Comment: Some people are in different time zones. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 3):

Let $G$ be the Klein $4$-group, namely $G = (\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)\times(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)$. Then $Z(G)=G$, and none of the three $2$-element subgroups of $G$ are characteristic subgroups.